Converting HTML to Image and Extracting a Mask for each word (wkhtmltoimage, anti-aliasing)
My problem is as follows: I have an HTML file that contains some text (rotated, varying font sizes and font families, but the color of the text is adjustable). I want to convert this HTML to an image using a tool like wkhtmltoimage or a headless browser.
I will be doing this for millions of files so speed does matter. From what I have experimented with, wkhtmltoimage is much faster than taking a screenshot in a headless browser.
Once we have converted the html to image, I want to extract segmentation masks for each word, line, and paragraph on the page (generating synthetic data for training a ML model).
Lastly, I would prefer to keep all of this in Python.
My approach was as follows:

I will render each word in the HTML file in a different color (using CSS).
Then convert the HTML to png using wkhtmltoimage.
Since each word is in a different color, I can extract the word segmentation masks based on the color.

In theory, since we have 16,777,216 colors in the RGB Color Space, I should be able to render all words on the page in different colors (as we would have no where near 16,777,216 words in a single page).
Where I'm stuck: It turns out, when we convert HTML to png (using wkhtmltoimage, or even take a screenshot), the image is anti-aliased. Edges are softened and the colors are not exactly as they were specified in the CSS.
I think this is called sub-pixel rendering. I've tried turning off Clear Type in Windows and that did not make any change.
I've also tried setting the quality of wkhtmltoimage to 100, which also did not get the intended result.
Turning off anti-aliasing in the Windows settings made a noticable difference in the image, but it was not enough to generate an accurate mask. Plus, it would be great if the users of the software did not have to tweak their OS settings.

So, if the T has a shade of red that is (200, 0, 0) and I have another word in the page that has the same shade of red, when I attempt to mask that word, some parts of the T will also be in that mask.
I'm able to extract these masks using OpenCV in Python. But, due to the anti-aliasing/sub-pixel rendering issue, the masks are not accurate, as described above.

So, is there a way that I can generate accurate masks from my HTML converted to an image?
Thanks in advance.

"Once we have converted the html to image, I want to extract segmentation masks for each word, line, and paragraph on the page" -- seems a bit counterproductive, when you have the source HTML used to render the output, an the renderer already jad to figure out where (and how large) each of the elements should be rendered.
